# Using colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot, the color of points is determined by a variable with classes, so something like this

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=my_var)
```

Now I want to plot another point into this plot, I have a value of this point's class, I would like the color to be the same as of points already plotted

```
plt.scatter(some_x, some_y, c=value)
```

So say, `my_var = [0, 1, 2, 3]` and `value = 2`. How do I make the color of point with `some_x, some_y` coordinates the same color as points in the first plot of the same class?

Comment: can you add a picture of what you need and what you already have?

Comment: To get the same range for the colors, vmin and vmax need to be set. E.g. `plt.scatter(some_x, some_y, c=value, vmin=min(my_var), vmax=max(my_var))`